# php output into middle of page

Tags: php, html, cgi

For my website I have a template file that is included in all files and contains functions for outputting all of the consistent elements across all pages on my site, including a footer.

I am trying to have a page that will load to the point of having all of this content in place and then go back and add the output from a call to `system` in the content element.

Does anybody have any ideas how this could be done? I can get it to output the result of `system` the way I need, but the footer is always added after the last line from this call...

EDIT:

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<?php
OutputHeader();

OutputContentLineByLine();

OutputFooter();
?>
```

Where `OutputHeader` puts the page header, `OutputFooter` puts the page footer and `OutputContentLineByLine` calls an external program with `system` and outputs the result line by line. The footer should be output before the content but show before the content.

Comment: You can use PHP Output buffering check this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php‎

Comment: Thanks for the link, but could you please elaborate which of the methods listed at your link could be used to achieve this effect?  Editing my question to add an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: not sure what you mean when you say "system"